# compare filenames in 2 folders and move the unmatched files to a separate folder in

Tags: r

I have 2 folders A and B with 5000 and 6000 files respectively. Folder B is a subset of the folder A. I need to compare these two folders and moves the unmatched files to a separate folder C. How could this be done in R by just comparing the filenames and moving them

Comment: How about exploring `list.files()`, to get names then use `%in%` to find which files are present and then maybe `file.rename` or `file.copy()`.

Comment: %in% of the folder A and B gives me all FALSE. What does this mean? There are additional files in folder A and how could I find and separate them?

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to list the files in their respective directory (here with the directory for A as example:

```
flsA <- list.files(dirA,patt,full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

With `patt` you can specify a pattern string, like a file extension, e.g. `".txt$"` (note the `$` at the end telling R it's the end of the filename).

If there are sub-directories you want to include, you can set `recursive` to `TRUE`.

The `full.names` option gives the full paths and is necessary for moving files later.

When you have both directories listed, you can compare the contained files with the functions `basename` and `%in%`:

```
ix <- basename(flsA) %in% basename(flsB)
```

This will give you a logical vector (`TRUE` for files in both `A` and `B`) which you can then use for indexing the files you want:

```
to_move <- flsA[!ix]
```

I'm using the `!` operator to reverse the logical vector as I want the files which are not in both directories.

Finally you can `lapply` the function you want to your files, e.g.:

```
lapply(to_move, function(x) file.copy(x,new.dir_C)
```

Once they are copied correctly, you could use `file.remove` to get rid of the originals:

```
lapply (to_move,file.remove)
```

Comment: The code works great. But the problem is with the filenames. I have filenames of folder A as follows:ECGV0007_wholecaseRRiQTi, ECGV0009_wholecaseRRiQTi..........ECGV103113_wholecaseRRiQTi,ECGVS1-7662_wholecaseRRiQTi.... and filenames of folder B as: ECGV0007_After_1stSleepOnset_RRiQTi, ECGV103106_After_1stSleepOnset_RRiQTi etc. Which means that the numbers alone match/unmatch . How do I make a comparison of these files

Comment: This constitutes a separate question or at least a modification of your original question. If the filenaming is consistent, regular expressions would be the way to go. If you update your question, add an exemplary case for a filename and then I'll see if i can update my answer